# How can I make a default parameter in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I make a Typescript function parameter have a default value ?

I have this code:

```
modalSubmit = (autoSave) => {

    var self = this;
    self.stateService.network('Submitting');
    self.modal.resetDisabled = true;
    self.modal.submitDisabled = true;
    autoSave = autoSave || false;
```

Is there a way with Typescript that I can make autoSave default to false if it's not set ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep:  http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/javascript-default-parameters-with-typescript-tutorial/

```
modalSubmit = (autoSave: boolean = false) => {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, if you are wondering how you should check for a value in pure JS:

```
autoSave = autoSave !== undefined ? autoSave : false;
```

Of course typescript does it for you.